# Why is there no newsletter available?

Tags: discussion, bug

I couldn't find any option to subscribe to the newsletter and even in the dashboard, where all sites are listed, subscribing "ask patents" is not possible.
Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

Newsletters have been renamed to **community digests**. You can subscribe to them on [SE.com](https://stackexchange.com/digests). You can also get there via your [email settings](https://patents.stackexchange.com/users/email/settings/current).

[image]